# How to do a union with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all

I am still learning to write it and below query is not giving me accurate results plus it is also not optimized.

So one of the main things that I am trying to do is create 3 date types:

- sales_shift,
- refund,
- sales_reg

in my data sets.

To achieve this I am doing a union.

All 3 data sets are querying the same source `sales_main`. The problem is in my 2nd data set with ‘Refund’ as date_type, it is not pulling the actual rows because of ColumnA = ‘B’ condition.

I would like this set to look at only those records that were pulled in 1st data set (i.e ‘Sales_shift’ as date_type) and then apply the condition ColumnA = ‘B’. How do I do that?

My 3rd data set with ‘sales_reg’ as date_type should be same  as 1st set except with transaction_date not shifted. How do I do that. I was thinking of where exists but do not know how to apply it.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks much

```
create table sales_refund as select * from (
with table1 as (select 'Sales_shift' as date_type,
            add_months(date_trunc('month',transaction_date),1) as event_date,
            sku,
            sum(sales) as Sales_total,
            sum(refund) as Refund_total,
            case when region in ('US','EU') then 'type A' else 'type B' end as Flag_field1
            from sales_main where transaction_date >= add_months(current_date(),-6)
            group by sku,
            'Sales_shift' 
            add_months(date_trunc('month',transaction_date),1),
            Flag_field1),
table2 as (select sku,
                 date_type,
                 event_date,
                 Sales_total,
                 Refund_total,
                 Flag_field1,
                 case when Flag_field1 = 'type B' or (Flag_field1 = 'type A' and Sales_total > 20000) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Flag_field2

                      from table1 )
Select       sku,
                 date_type,
                 event_date,
                 Sales_total,
                 Refund_total,
                 Flag_field1
     fromm table2 where Flag_field2 = 'Yes' )

union all        
               select  sku,
           'Refund' as date_type,
            date_trunc('month',refund_date) as event_date,
            sum(sales) as Sales_total,
            sum(refund) as Refund_total,
            'X' as Flag_field1
            from sales_main where transaction_date >= add_months(current_date(),-6) and ColumnA = 'B'
            group by sku,
            'Refund' 
            date_trunc('month',refund_date),
            'X'

union all        
               select  sku,
           'Sales_Reg' as date_type,
            date_trunc('month',transaction_date) as event_date,
            sum(sales) as Sales_total,
            sum(refund) as Refund_total,
            'Y' as Flag_field1
            from sales_main where transaction_date >= add_months(current_date(),-6) 
            group by sku,
            'Refund' 
            date_trunc('month',transaction_date),
            'Y'
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide some sample input data that mimics the results of the table1 subquery, along with the expected outcome of your query.

Comment: need to replace `current_date()` with `current_date`